# C# Execute method against property info

Tags: c#

I have a Func that finds a specific property, but now I also want to execute extension method against that property.

So normally running extension method would look like this:

```
.Where(t => t.DocumentVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery($"{ticket}:*")))
```

But I want to make some adjustments to where expression, so i thought I can use something like:

```
Func<Tickets, bool> func = t =>
{
    var vectorIndexProperty = t.GetType().GetProperty("DocumentVector");
    //more adjustments or aggregations
    return vectorIndexProperty.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery($"{ticket}:*")); // here is the peroblem
};

.Where(t => func(t)) //result
```

So my questions is, How can I execute method against property that I found using reflection?

**Edit**

I could use aggregations and that would be like:

```
var predicate = new List<Expression<Func<Tickets, bool>>>
{
    t => t.DocumentVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery($"{ticket}:*"))
};

var query = 
    predicate.Aggregate(this._context.Tickets.AsQueryable(), 
        (@event, condition) => @event.Where(condition));

var result = query.Select(t => t.TicketNo).OrderBy(t => t).Take(10);
```

Instead of Func I could use expression aggregates but what about scenario where I have a 50 possible conditions, my plan was to do check if property exists and execute method on that property (instead of doing 50 conditions), if it does not exists skip it.

Is it possible in this scenario ?

Comment: If the intent is to "encapsulate" the `Func` for further use in EF, be aware this will not work even if you manage to invoke the extension method (which just means invoking it as a static method, through its `MethodInfo`), since it will no longer be a query that EF can translate. You'd have to build the entire query expression dynamically, which is much more complicated than what's happening here.

Comment: I made some adjustments to my question, with you're suggestion of using expressions.

Comment: It's not clear why you'd be dealing with dynamic properties. EF's primary use case deals with statically mapping between objects and tables. It sounds like you either need something entirely different from EF (whether it's Dapper, DynamicLINQ, a different way of constructing queries on the source directly that avoids EF, or moving to LINQ to Objects after retrieval), or just different source queries. Trying to combine EF with dynamism is very much trying to fit a round peg in a square hole -- probably possible if you force it, but likely not the cleanest solution.

Comment: Aye, maybe I should loom out of the box on this